# Inputting name strings with spaces into struct in C

Tags: c, input, struct, output

I am making a program that accepts input of name (max length of name is 100 characters, name can be one word, two words, and multiple words), and the date of birth of the person. You can focus on the name input only, the other code is just fine)

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char ksg[] = "kosong";
struct database{
    int urutan;
    char nama[101]; //array that will contain the characters
    int tanggal;
    int bulan;
    int tahun;
    int umur;
} no[100];
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%[^\n]s", no[i].nama); //This is the name input
        scanf("%d/%d/%d",&no[i].tanggal, &no[i].bulan, &no[i].tahun);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        if(no[i].bulan>12){
            strcpy(no[i].nama,ksg);
            no[i].tanggal = 1;
            no[i].bulan = 1;
            no[i].tahun = 1;
            no[i].umur = -1;
        }
        else if(no[i].bulan==1 ||no[i].bulan==3 ||no[i].bulan==5 ||no[i].bulan==7 ||no[i].bulan==8 ||no[i].bulan==10 ||no[i].bulan==12){
            if(no[i].tanggal>31){
                strcpy(no[i].nama,ksg);
                no[i].tanggal = 1;
                no[i].bulan = 1;
                no[i].tahun = 1;
                no[i].umur = -1;
            }
        }
        else if(no[i].bulan==4 ||no[i].bulan==6 ||no[i].bulan==9 ||no[i].bulan==11){
            if(no[i].tanggal>30){
                strcpy(no[i].nama,ksg);
                no[i].tanggal = 1;
                no[i].bulan = 1;
                no[i].tahun = 1;
                no[i].umur = -1;
            }
        }
        else if(no[i].bulan == 2 && no[i].tahun%4!=0){
            if(no[i].tanggal>28){
                strcpy(no[i].nama,ksg);
                no[i].tanggal = 1;
                no[i].bulan = 1;
                no[i].tahun = 1;
                no[i].umur = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        if(no[i].umur!=-1){
            no[i].umur = 2020-no[i].tahun;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        printf("Orang ke : %d\n", i+1);
        printf("Nama: %s\n", no[i].nama); //This outputs the name
        printf("TL  : %d-%d-%d\n", no[i].tanggal, no[i].bulan, no[i].tahun);
        if(no[i].umur==-1){
            printf("Sepertinya ada kesalahan\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("%d\n", no[i].umur-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I already tried using

```
fgets(no[i].nama,100,stdin)

gets(no[i].nama)

scanf(%[^\n]s, no[i].nama)
```

And I have read a lot of solutions of similar questions, one which checks the newline character and trims it, one which was using getchar() after scanf.

Sample input and output :
input :

```
3
Hugo Broadway
21/1/1999
James Out
30/3/2000
Billy Bo
17/4/1997
```

expected output

```
Orang ke : 1
Nama: Hugo Broadway
TL  : 21-1-1999
Umur: 19
Orang ke : 2
Nama: James Out
TL  : 30-3-2000
Umur: 18
Orang ke : 3
Nama: Billy Bo
TL  : 17-4-1997
Umur: 21
```

My output

```
Orang ke : 1
Nama: 
TL  : 0-0-0
Umur: 2019
Orang ke : 2
Nama: Hugo Broadway
TL  : 21-1-1999
Umur: 20
Orang ke : 3
Nama: 
TL  : 0-0-0
Umur: 2019
```

Comment: The `%[]` format specifier is *only* `%[]` (and the pattern inside the brackets). The  `scanf` function will try to match the trailing `s` you have in `%[^\n]s` literally in the input. Furthermore, the `%[]` format does not skip leading white-space, you need to tell `scanf` to do it explicitly, like adding a leading space in the format string. As in `" %[^\n]"`. Lastly, if you want to read whole lines, I really recommend that you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: And a note about `gets`: Never ***ever*** use that function. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that is have even been removed from the C standard (and was obsolete a long time before that).

Comment: I already tried fgets, it doesn't work, has the same output

Comment: When you do `scanf("%d", &t)` what do you use to end that input? The `Enter` key? Then please reread my first comment, especially about the `%[]` format ***not** skipping leading space* like the newline added by that `Enter` key.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I realized it's because of the enter key after scanf("%d", &t). I used getchar before scanning the name and now everything's fine. Thanks!